# Extract all keys from JSON string which is a key value pair

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a pretty simple JSON string as shown below

> x =  '{ "Text1":"Value1", "Text2":"Value2", "Text3":"Value3"}'

I would like to store all keys in one list and all values in another list. I do not want to use a loop as this json is going to be very huge with KVP

I tried to get help from google but haven't got anything which satisfies the requirement.

Comment: `list(json.loads(x).keys())` and `list(json.loads(x).values())`

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a nested JSON then

```
d = dict({ "Text1":"Value1", "Text2":"Value2", "Text3":"Value3"})
print(d.keys());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import json

x = '{ "Text1":"Value1", "Text2":"Value2", "Text3":"Value3"}'

keys, values = map(list, zip(*json.loads(x).items()))

print(keys)    # ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3']
print(values)  # ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']
```